# Set parameters of custom column Transformer in SKlearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, parameters

I want to cross-validate parameters of custom column transformer:

```
def make_target_preprocessor(min_samples_leaf, smoothing):
    return make_column_transformer(
        (TargetEncoder(min_samples_leaf=min_samples_leaf, smoothing=smoothing),
        make_column_selector('^utm')),
        (Pipeline(steps=[
            ('imputer', DeviceBrandImputer()),
            ('encoder', TargetEncoder(min_samples_leaf=min_samples_leaf, smoothing=smoothing))
        ]),
        ['device_category', 'device_brand', 'device_browser'])
    )
    
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessor', make_target_preprocessor(min_samples_leaf=20, smoothing=10)),
    ('clf', LogisticRegression(max_iter=10000, random_state=11))
])

param = [{'preprocessor__min_samples_leaf': [5, 10, 20]]}]
gs_lr = GridSearchCV(pipe, param)
```

But there is an error:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter 'min_samples_leaf' for estimator ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('targetencoder', TargetEncoder(),
                                 <sklearn.compose._column_transformer.make_column_selector object at 0x7f951565ad00>),
                                ('pipeline-1',
                                 Pipeline(steps=[('imputer'...
```

How do I can properly pass min_samples_leaf to make_target_preprocessor through GridSearchCV?

Answer (score 0):

You can't accomplish shared hyperparameters this way.  When you create `pipe`, this line

```py
    ('preprocessor', make_target_preprocessor(min_samples_leaf=20, smoothing=10)),
```

is *calling the function* `make_target_preprocessor` with a fixed `min_samples_leaf=20`, returning a `ColumnTransformer` object.  Its hyperparameters can be inspected, and there will be two different `min_samples_leaf`, one for each target encoder.

The easiest thing to do is just search over those two `min_samples_leaf` separately.

If you really want to tie them together, you can manage in this case by moving the target encoding outside of the column transformer:

```py
preproc = Pipeline([
    ('impute', make_column_transformer(
        (DeviceBrandImputer(), ['device_category', 'device_brand', 'device_browser']),
        remainder='passthrough',
    )),
    ('encode', TargetEncoder(min_samples_leaf=min_samples_leaf, smoothing=smoothing)),
])
```

For a more general transformer setup, I think you need a custom transformer class.